# building framework-res.apk, system crashes after replace

Tags: android

I am trying to add two buttons .xml file which is in /frameworks/base/core/res/res/.
I can add buttons without any "android:id" attribute for button view and that works properly on device too. But if try to give id to the buttons added to access them from .java files, the systems is not able to bootup ( all system services are dieing )

how can i give id to the button in xml file ?
please can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found answer for this problem and solution is very simple, build the whole source again :)